# How to add our own button to the title bar on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

As we can see the button left side of the minimize button(-) in google chrome, like that i want to add one more button on the title bar of any browser when I run the application(which developed in C# MVC) using jquery or javascript or any plugin support to do this.

Comment: You can't do anything outside body of browser

Comment: You mean that i can't achieve this task?

Comment: No, not without changing the browser itself

Comment: Yes...you can't achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Chrome offers you an option to add your own JavaScript programs into the browser while making use of a provided API.

Here you can find an introduction: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

The API won't give you all the possibility you might need, just some function google think you should be allowed to access.